# How to load secondary contacts in android?

Tags: android, contacts

I am developing an android application. I want to extract information (e.g secondary phone number of home or office) from contacts. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need run a query for all phones..

```
            Cursor phones = cr.query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = " + id, null, null);
            try {
                phones.moveToFirst();
                while (!phones.isAfterLast()) {
                    ContactPhone phone = new ContactPhone();
                    String number = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER));
                    // 0 = false | 1 = true
                    int primary = phones.getInt(phones.getColumnIndex(Phone.IS_PRIMARY));
                    int type = phones.getInt(phones.getColumnIndex(Phone.TYPE));
                    //Do whatever you want with this info
                    phones.moveToNext();
                }
            } finally {
                if (phones != null) {
                    phones.close();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Hi Rafeel how to get the secondary phone number that means the work phone number or other ones

Comment: running this query you are getting all phones of a contact. The field `type` keeps the value of the Phone type...you can compare it to get the correct type, like this:

`if(type == Phone.TYPE_WORK){
     //it's a work phone
}else if(type == Phone.TYPE_MOBILE){
    //Mobile phone..
}`